# How do I translate « si bien que »?

Tags: traduction

As far as I know, « si » is translated as " if " and « bien que » is translated as " although " but " if although " doesn't make any sense in English, so how would I understand « si bien que » in a sentence like « Si bien que la nonviolence est, pour la victime, une façon de répondre à partir d'une position de puissance, plutôt que de faiblesse ou de peur. »?

Comment: What did Deepl tell you? And a [dictionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/si_bien_que)? Consider *si bien que* is a phrase in itself, don't try to split it too much.

Comment: @None Linguee, where I got that sentence from, says "in that respect" but in the sentence "Je suis allé à l'université juste après l'école secondaire mais j'ai détesté ça, si bien que j'ai décroché" it translates it as "so" instead. So I wondered if there was a condensed way to understand this phrase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Si bien que"  is a conjunctival locution  ([Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/si_bien_que)) meaning "so much so that".

> ([M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/so%20much%20so%20(that))) **so much so (that)** : to the extent that
> ♦ The twins look alike—so much so that even their parents sometimes confuse them.

So, you can translate it by "so much so that" or "to the extent that".